# header semaphore.h can not include eclipse juno. I get the error "unresolved inclusion"

Tags: c++, c, eclipse

I`m trying to test the codes from a tutorial about multithreading in C language. I have eclipse JUNO and Mingw and Cygwin64 installed on a windows 7, 64x. I have also set the variable path.  When i add headers like stdio.h, pthread_time.h or fcntl.h i have no problems but when i try to include the headers semaphore.h or pthread.h, eclipse gives me the error "unresolved inclusion." Can any one help me? Any help is heartly appreciated.

[update from comment:]

I`m using: Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers Version: Juno Service Release 2 and i have c++ version 4.7.0. But remember i,m making the program is c.

These are some includes and the way i do:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <pthread_time.h> 
#include <pthread_unistd.h> 
#include <semaphore.h> 
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("Hello World");
   }
```

As i said not by all of them i have problem but only by semaphore.h and pthread.h i get the error. Actually i dont need all of those headers for such a simple program, but that is only as an example.

Comment: Hi I don't use the same IDE or compiler as you in windows, but do the files exists? What version of c++ are you using? Could you please provide your code and some more information?

Comment: Hi, this is the version i`m using: Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers Version: Juno Service Release 2 and i have c++ version 4.7.0. But remember i,m making the program is c. These are some includes and the way i do:        #include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread_time.h>
#include <pthread_unistd.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <fcntl.h>    As i said not by all of them i have problem but only by semaphore.h and pthread.h i get the error.    Thanks for ur attention.

Comment: Hi edit your original post rather than adding it in the comments, it makes it more readable for others. I'm not sure, but I would checked the include directories that the files exists.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was easier than i thought: just use cygwin instead mingw by making the project as toolchain.